# The best way to implement a background service in Grails

Tags: grails, service, grails-orm

I have done a lot of searching and I am aware of grails-executor and the JMS plugin.  I am looking for advice on the best way to implement a long running (as long as the application is running) service that runs in the background and accepts input on a blocking queue.  It seems that there at two ways to satisfy my requirements... 1. JMS (which feels overly heavy handed) and 2. a service running on a thread that watches the queue... when something is added to it, it processes it and then waits for the next item.  This service needs to have GORM capability so that it can create/save objects.  My preference is to startup some type of service on a thread and use a blocking queue... Can anyone suggest the best way to do this?  Should I just implement a class that gets called when grails bootstraps and have that class use the grails-executor to create a thread that just runs in the background?  If anyone has used the jms plugin in grails, is it sufficiently lightweight that I should reconsider my position on this?  Any and all advice is greatly appreciated.  I am really NOT tied to any one solution, so all ideas will be considered and very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Spring integration instead. With quartz you have to develop you enqueuing logic but with spring integration every thing is pre-developed.

Answer (score 3):

I use the quartz plugin for a lot of similar "queue watching" functionality.

Comment: I thought about Quartz, but I want this service to run while the app is running and not really on a schedule. If quartz as a "only at startup" option, then that could work - i would just have it fire up a background thread that survives for the life of the app... I will look into whether or not it has that option. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you have a slight misunderstanding of how quartz works.  Yes, it runs on a schedule, but it's a job, that kicks off a service (a Grails service in your case).  So every 5 minutes (or whatever you choose) it kicks off the service method, then you do whatever you want.  It will continue to do so, until you shut it down.  And the rest of your app just keeps on plugging a long.  It doesn't wait for the quartz job to do anything.  It just keeps handling requests.